# Pressure as a function of altitude above 11 km

Tags: barometric-pressure

I need to calculate the force that causes a weather balloon with a specific volume to rise. Having searched for quite a few hours, I found the needed formula that can be used to calculate the pressure at a certain altitude. (surprisingly, the formula given on the [German](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometrische_H%C3%B6henformel#Internationale_H.C3.B6henformel) Wikipedia gives better values than that from the [English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula) one )

This is needed to get the density of the air, which can then be used with Archimedes' principle to get the buoyancy force of the balloon a that height.

However, it is stated that the formula only returns valid values for altitudes up to 11 km. Is there a way to calculate the air pressure at a higher altitude?

Comment: Really not surprising the Germany page has better formulas.  The atmospheric scientists in Germany are remarkable.

Comment: How did you determine one gave better answers than the other?

Comment: @farrenthorpe - The quality of wikipedia pages in different languages has very little to do with the quality of scientists who speak that language.

Comment: The formula given on the German wikipedia was much easier to use than the other one; however, that (two) formulars can be used to caclulate the pressure (there are others for the density, too) up to 84 km.

Comment: @Tacticus can you add the two equations (German vs English wiki) to the question? Entries in Wikipedia change with time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those formulas are based on an assumption that the pressure is hydrostatic and the ideal gas law. The example given is limited to 11km but uses the tables from the [U.S. Standard Atmosphere](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19770009539_1977009539.pdf) which actually go up to $1000$ km. Starting at Page 58 one can find values for pressure density and temperature above 11km.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The original description of the [US. Standard Atmosphere 1976](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2UKsBO-ZMVgWG9mWEJGMlFacDQ/edit?pli=1) turns out to include much more and detailed information than the Wikipedia article. I've now, finally, got it working using the fixed variables $H_b$, $\rho_b$, $T_b$ and $L_b$, which determine the standard height, (air) density, temperature and lapse rate at layer $b$, respectively. A sufficient overview of those values can be found on the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula#Density_equations).

This approach gives quite accurate results, which fit to the values supplied by Isopycnal Oscillation.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be central reference for standard temperature and atmospheric pressure at high altitudes. Below is the code I wrote after combining two resources that can be found in the comments. This C++ code calculates standard atmospheric pressure all the way up to 86km.

```
  float getStandardPressure(float altitude /* meters */)   //return Pa
  {
    //Below 51km: Practical Meteorology by Roland Stull, pg 12
    //Above 51km: http://www.braeunig.us/space/atmmodel.htm
    //Validation data: https://www.avs.org/AVS/files/c7/c7edaedb-95b2-438f-adfb-36de54f87b9e.pdf

    altitude = altitude / 1000.0f;  //convert meters to km
    float geopot_height = getGeopotential(altitude);

    float t = getStandardTemperature(geopot_height);

    if (geopot_height <= 11)
      return  101325 * pow(288.15f / t, -5.255877f);
    else if (geopot_height <= 20)
      return 22632.06 * exp(-0.1577f * (geopot_height - 11));
    else if (geopot_height <= 32)
      return 5474.889f * pow(216.65f / t, 34.16319f);
    else if (geopot_height <= 47)
      return 868.0187f * pow(228.65f / t, 12.2011f);
    else if (geopot_height <= 51)
      return 110.9063f * exp(-0.1262f * (geopot_height - 47));
    else if (geopot_height <= 71)
      return 66.93887f * pow(270.65f / t, -12.2011f);
    else if (geopot_height <= 84.85)
      return 3.956420f * pow(214.65f / t, -17.0816f);

    throw std::out_of_range("altitude must be less than 86km. Space domain is not supported yet!");    
  }

  //geopot_height = earth_radius * altitude / (earth_radius + altitude) /// all in kilometers
  //temperature is in Kelvin = 273.15 + celcius
  float getStandardTemperature(float geopot_height) 
  {
    //standard atmospheric pressure
    //Below 51km: Practical Meteorology by Roland Stull, pg 12
    //Above 51km: http://www.braeunig.us/space/atmmodel.htm
    if (geopot_height <= 11)          //troposphere
      return 288.15f - (6.5 * geopot_height);
    else if (geopot_height <= 20)     //Staroshere starts
      return 216.65f;
    else if (geopot_height <= 32)
      return 196.65f + geopot_height;
    else if (geopot_height <= 47)       
      return 228.65f + 2.8 * (geopot_height - 32);
    else if (geopot_height <= 51)     //Mesosphere starts
      return 270.65f;
    else if (geopot_height <= 71)       
      return 270.65f - 2.8 * (geopot_height - 51);
    else if (geopot_height <= 84.85)    
      return 214.65f - 2 * (geopot_height - 71);    
    //Thermospehere has high kinetic temperature (500c to 2000c) but temperature
    //as measured by thermometer would be very low because of almost vaccume
    throw std::out_of_range("geopot_height must be less than 85km. Space domain is not supported yet!");
  }

  float getGeopotential(float altitude_km)
  {
    constexpr float EARTH_RADIUS =  6356.766; //km
    return EARTH_RADIUS * altitude_km / (EARTH_RADIUS + altitude_km);
  }
```

Comment: That seems practical.